# Página em branco ao executar comando sql

Tags: php, mysql, post

Quando executo a pagina index.php, existe um form que vai para a página login.php

Quando é executada a página login fica totalmente em branco, não executa nada.

O Codigo é o seguinte:

```
<?php
include_once("../../conf.php");

$mysqli = mysqli_connect(HOST,user,PASS,DB) or die (mysqli_error());

$login = $_POST['login'];
$senha = $_POST['senha'];

if ($prep = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM Admin WHERE login=? AND password=?")) {
    $prep->bind_param('ss',$login,$senha);
    $prep->execute();

    if ($prep->error) {
        echo "erro";
    } else {
        echo "ok";
    }
} else {
    echo "erro 2";
}
```

O diretorio onde está o conf.php existe, é uma simples ligação à base de dados usando mysqli_connect.

O que se poderá passar? Nem uma mensagem de erro nem nada..

Comment: Adicione essas linhas no início do arquivo: ini_set('display_errors', true); error_reporting(E_ALL); Depois poste o erro.

Comment: Não aparece rigorosamente nada...

Comment: Acesse direto o arquivo `conf.php` veja se não tem nenhum erro nele, adicione aquelas duas linhas nele também.

Comment: Algumas destas respostas lhe atenderam?

Answer (score 1):

Olá.

Experimente o seguinte:

Onde tens o `mysqli_connect` coloque simplesmente `new mysqli`.

Answer (score 0):

Não esta faltando algo como:

```
printf("%d Row inserted.\n", $stmt->affected_rows);
```

Veja a documentação oficial: [Documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)